# ParseException with semicolon ';'

Tags: hive, concatenation, special-characters, hiveql

I trying to select some data with string constants. There is an

```
ParseException line 3:21 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>'
```

after adding the '=', ';' signs.

```
select
  t.*,
  concat('=test;',t.id),
  t.other_id
from service t;
```

Could you tell me what is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is only with semicolon. It needs escaping. Escape semicolon with double-slash `\\;` or replace with `\073`.

In hive cli both work fine. In beeline use `\073`.

Change in your query:

```
concat('=test\\;',t.id)
```

or

```
concat('=test\073',t.id)
```